# Cannot inspect variables when debugging source mapped JS files in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-2015, source-maps

I am unable to inspect the contents of variables in Visual Studio while I am debugging a source-mapped JS file. I can hit breakpoints in the original JS file without any issues but I am unable to see what is inside each of the variables like I used to before implementing the minified version and the source map.

The file we'll use for this example is sessionStatus.js. In my project, I have Build Action: None for sessionStatus.js, Build Action: Content for sessionStatus.min.js, and Build Action: Content for sessionStatus.min.js.map.

Visual Studio project layout:

[image: sessionStatus.js]

[image]

As you can see here, I'm hitting my breakpoints in the original source file but I cannot inspect any of the variables:

[image]

My files look like so:

**Index.html** (relevant section):

```
<script src="app/controllers/sessionStatus.min.js"></script>
```

**sessionStatus.min.js**

[image]

**sessionStatus.min.js.map**

[image]

**bundleconfig.json**

[image]

My end-goal here is to be able to debug in Visual Studio using my original javascript source files but include only the minified files in the deployed version.

Comment: Please check that whether it was related to the debugging option like "Use Managed/Native Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->OPTIONS->Debugging. My understanding is that if just the specific app has this issue, if possible, you could share a simple sample using one drive, I will download and debug it in my side using the same Environment as yours.

Comment: Could you view the variables in debugging window now?

Comment: Hi Jack. I'm sorry but I had to move onto another project. I ended up reverting to my pre-minification code base for now.

Comment: So you mean that it has no this issue in your previous project version, am I right? Anyway, if you will go back to your previous project code, you could close this case now. If you meet any debugging issue, you could start a new thread in the future:) Have a nice day, Ian.